# Importing specific fields/columns of a CSV file with mySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am wanting to import certains fields of a CSV, not all of them.

I am using: (MySQL)

```
load data infile 'pathToCSV' 
into table 'tablename' 
fields terminated by ',' 
lines terminated by '\n';
```

Is there a way to only load specific fields from the CSV? For example, field 1 of csv is field 1 of table, but field 3 of csv is field 2 of table. TIA for answers :)

Comment: Import all cols into a temp table and then seect from that into the real table

Comment: Of use something like PHP to read the CSV and write to the DB